# Div element adding whitespace to custom VB coverage report

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a really simple coverage report using the most basic html and css. Here's what I have so far:

```css
pre div {
  background-color: green;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<pre>
  <code>
<div>Option Explicit</div>
Sub HelloWorld()
    Debug.Print("Hello World")
End Sub
  </code>
</pre>
```

This works OK, but the `div` tag seems to add some white space between the line which contains `Option Explicit` and the line containing `Sub HelloWorld`. I do not want this.

Why is the div element adding this whitespace and how can I remove it?

Comment: inside `pre` all the spaces counts so you see what you write

Comment: So why is it that if I replace the `div` with a `span` the whitespace disappears?

Comment: because div is a block element and you aren't allowed to have block inside inline element (code) to start with

Comment: add border to the code element and read the duplicate to understand what is happening

Comment: Ok, I had a look at the duplicate and I understand that `div` is a block element, so putting that inside the `code` (which is an inline element) is bad practice.

However, I still need to find a way to shade the entire line. Therefore I don't think this question is a duplicate of the one provided.

Answer (score 0):

Change to: `display: inline-block;` 
Add: `width: 100%;` to keep the *background-color* at 100% width

```css
pre div {
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<pre>
<code>
<div>Option Explicit</div>
Sub HelloWorld()
    Debug.Print("Hello World")
End Sub
</code>
</pre>
```

Comment: I need the entire line to be shaded with the background color from one end of the window to the other. This code only shades the background of `Option Explicit`

Comment: Because the *selector* is `pre div`, if you tried `pre { background-color: green; }` then it'll style the `pre` element including `Sub Hello World()...` till `End Sub`, if that what you are asking for.